# Broadcast the method ArrayList.add from one Class to another Class with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I try to use `Intent` to broadcast my text from the EditText field to my spinner witch using a ArrayList.

One class looks like:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> server_name_list;
    ...
    ...
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.server_spinner);
    server_name_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list");

    server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> server_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, server_name_list);

    server_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(server_adapter);
```

So I try to get the new item to my ArrayList by using

**AddIP.java**

```
public class AddIP extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> server_name_list;
    ...
    ...
/* Add IP Button */
    btn_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
    server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
```

In the same class it works.
But I have one class with the EditText field and one with the spinner (in the MainActivity.class).

And here is the Intent method

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AddIP.this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list", server_name_list);
```

But if I click on the "Add IP" button my programm crashs.
What did I wrong?

**Error-Code while debuggin**

```
11-13 15:19:27.875 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime: Process: de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview, PID: 7422
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview.AddIP$2.onClick(AddIP.java:49)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    11-13 15:19:27.876 7422-7422/de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**EDIT**

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
...
 ArrayList<String> server_name_list;
...
...
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
 //Spinner
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.server_spinner);

        server_name_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list");

        server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayAdapter<String> server_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, server_name_list);

        server_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(server_adapter);
```

AddIP.java

```
public class AddIP extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_back, btn_add;
EditText server_ip, server_name;
String new_server_ip, new_server_name;
ArrayList<String> server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_ip);

    server_ip = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);
    server_name = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_name);

    /* Back Button */
    btn_back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    /* Add IP Button */
    btn_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*new_server_ip = server_ip.getText().toString();
            MainActivity.server_array_ip.add(new_server_ip);*/

            new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();

            server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            server_name_list.add(new_server_name);

            Intent intent = new Intent(AddIP.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list", server_name_list);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: why does it crash? can you provide any stacktrace?

Comment: @Kevin Esche edited my post

Comment: Can you show the initialization of server_name_list in AddIP class?

Comment: @Nanoc I've tried the solution from Aegis. But there is no new entry in my ArrayList

Comment: Sure, thats creating a new empty array, can you post the code where you load your arraylist with your data?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Look at the Edit from my question.

Comment: That code looks OK, you should get a arrayList with just one item whats wrong with that?

Comment: It works, but `Intent` dont work.

Comment: What IDE are you using? The crash that @Aegis helped you fix, would've been pointed out by the Android Studio IDE (intellij version)

Answer (score -1):

You should use OTTO Event Bus for sending data to other activity or you can make your arraylist that you want to edit as static, like this:

```
 public static ArrayList<String> server_name_list;
```

and then access it in you `onClick()` as:

```
MainActivity.server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
```

then notify the adapter where you want to show the list.

Answer (score -2):

the field `server_name_list` is null in AddIP.java.

it should either be

```
ArrayList<String> server_name_list = new Arraylist<String>;
```

at the top of the class or in the onClick method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
    server_name_list = new Arraylist<String>;
    server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
```

Maybe if in the MainActivity if you would remove `server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();` after `server_name_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list");` the arraylist will be filled with the parcelable data?

Update:

the first crash can easily be debugged. When something crashes always check the stack trace in the log. Alway check the log for the last reference to your own code in this case that is `at de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview.AddIP$2.onClick(AddIP.java:49)`. Pointing to the line 49 the onClick method in the AddIP class. The error message `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference` means you are calling a method on a Object that is null and therefore cannot be executed. Which would translate the object `server_name_list` which is an `java.util.ArrayList` is null and should be initialized before using.

The second issue could easily be resolved by running through the code with the debugger enabled and setting a breakpoint on the first assignment of `server_name_list` and then stepping through the code line by line.

Comment: Thanks. Now the App doesn't crash anymore. But there is no new entry in my ArrayList.

Comment: Maybe instead of immediately downvoting an answer you should debug your code a little better.

Comment: And you can see that I downvote you answere? I don't...
And I'm new at coding, sorry that I can't everything

Comment: Sorry was a bit cranky when I say the down vote. And immediately started point fingers which I should not have done. Also I updated my answer with some more info.